# When drop a table it says doesn't exists, when create it says that exists in SQL Server 2008R2

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a big strange error in SQL Server 2008R2:

I have the following statement:

```
DROP TABLE TEST_
-- here it says that this table doesn't exists

GO    

CREATE TABLE TEST_(
    [ID_] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ITEM_] NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [TEST_] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID_] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

-- here says that table already exists
```

Please follow comment. Did this fact happens to you also ?

I cannot re-create table. What have I to do ?

**PS: I have same database selected**

Comment: Your create table syntax is wrong. make it work and the table will be created.

Comment: Really ? Where is the mistake ?

Comment: I used from Management Studio, `script table` -> `create to` option

Comment: Your CONSTRAINT [TEST_] has the same name as your table so you have a name conflict. Change the CONSTRAINT name to something like [TEST_PK] and it should work.

Comment: Correct, that's the mistake :)

Comment: This is an easy mistake to make in SQL Server because it *looks* like tables are in a different namespace from stored proceures, functions, constraints and triggers, but they are not. Essentially all database objects must have distinct names.

Comment: Why are you putting meaningless underscores at the end of all the names?

Comment: That's standard name in company where I work for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you may be confused, it complains that 'TEST_' already exists, but likely it means the constraint 'test_' already exists; use a different name for the constraint, and it works OK for me.

Comment: Yes, that's the mistake. The big one :)

Answer (score 1):

**I cannot run your query, because of next error:**

*Msg 3701, Level 11, State 5, Line 1*
*Cannot drop the table 'TEST*', because it does not exist or you do not have permission._
*Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5*
*Incorrect syntax near '('.*
*Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 7*
*Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.*

**But when I modify your query to:**
CREATE TABLE TEST_(
    [ID_] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ITEM_] NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
**it works fine:**
*Command(s) completed successfully.*

Comment: The issue was abaout the name of constraint was same with table name

Answer (score 0):

Always do a check for Object existence and then drop it, in this whether Tables exists or not you will never get an ERROR in return but table will be drop if it does exists...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.TEST_', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.TEST_
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been answered already, but it may help someone with the same error.  If you happen to have a create table query tab up in Management Studio to create a table (where you define column names and datatypes - not write sql), left that tab open, dropped the table using a different query tab, and finally opened another create table query tab and try to create a table with the same name, you will get an error saying that the table cannot be created because the table already exists - even though subsequent DROP or EXISTS queries cannot find the table.  The solution is to close the first create table query tab and and it will let you save the new table.